# Exception while parsing JSON

Tags: java, json

i have a JSON:

```
String jsonString = "{"Tech":"{id :[""],techInside :["Java","C++"]}","id1":"","state":""}";
```

So i need the value of  techInside. How do i access that > I have tried:

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(jsonString);
string techInside = obj.getJSONObject("Tech").getJSONArray("techInside");
```

But it gave me an exception:`org.json.JSONException: Expected a ',' or '}' at 17.`
Tried Many other ways but spent a lot of time on it. Need some suggestions please.
Note: i am using escape characters in the string.So please ignore about the escaping characters in the jsonString

Comment: Have you looked at this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java?rq=1

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. As it is your code isn't even compilable, e.g. `string techInside` probably should be `String techInside` but besides that how do you expect to be able to cast the return value of `getJSONArray()` to `String`?

Comment: Your JSON is invalid, and `getJSONArray()` doesn't return a "string" (or even a `String`), it returns a `JSONArray`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON is invalid. There should be no `""` around objects (`{}`).

Try with this JSON-String:

```
String jsonString = "{\"Tech\":{\"id\":[\"\"], \"techInside\":[\"Java\", \"C++\"]}, \"id1\":\"\", \"state\":\"\"}"
```

Or without escaping

```
{"Tech":{"id":[""], "techInside":["Java", "C++"]}, "id1":"", "state":""}
```

Comment: Oh. Thanks for that. I just blindly used some online tool to validate the JSON. It gave me a green so didnt even had a look at it again. Let me try reformatting the JSON. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

I think the kind of json you are looking for is

{"Tech": {"id" : "", "techInside" : ["Java","C++"]},"id1":"","state":""}

Not sure, what your requirement is.